# The iisnode module is unable to start the node.exe process

Tags: iis, next.js, deployment

The iisnode module is unable to start the node.exe process. Make sure the node.exe executable is available at the location specified in the system.webServer/iisnode/@nodeProcessCommandLine element of web.config. By default node.exe is expected in one of the directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

I am trying deploy next.js app on iis server and I am getting above error.

Will appricaiate any kind of help

I tried many sollutions but this is what I got at the end of  all other issues.

Here is my web.config  file

[image]

Below is my server.js file

[image]

I have these two files in my physical path folder along with .next folder which contains build created from npm run build command.

Comment: Is the nodejs you installed 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: You might easily miss some permissions, but IISNode might not be able to tell exactly. You can switch to HttpPlatformHandler to simplify the steps, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs and then troubleshooting is also easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the following two points:

First you need to check if Node.js is installed correctly on the server, you must be able to find node.exe in the default path: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`. And make sure the path to the node.exe executable is correctly added to your system's PATH environment variable.

Then check that the correct path to node.exe is specified in the configuration file of iisnode. If your nodejs is 32-bit, it will be installed in the "Program Files (x86)" location by default. The node.exe path in the configuration file should be modified to:

`<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files (x86)\ nodejs\node.exe" />`